# Sorry this video cannot be played in Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play a video in my Android app, and used the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showVideo();
}
private void showVideo()
{
    VideoView vd = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://package/"+R.raw.movie);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    vd.setMediaController(mc);
    vd.setVideoURI(uri);
    vd.start();
}
```

Using this code, I am getting an error that the video can not be played.

Comment: What is your video file type,mp4 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought...should your URI really have "package" in the path? shouldn't you replace that with your actual application package: "com.whatever.something"?

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackagename.appname/"+R.raw.movie);

Answer (score 0):

You want to getPackageName, or provide it by hand to get it to work:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.movie);
```